# Compile Error Error in Dev C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dev-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dev c++ compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733511/dev-c-compiler-error)

I have written a quite simple Windows application in Dev-C++ (actually it is the Dev-C++ default project template).

U have got this error

```
E:\proj1\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1
```

This is the compiler log :

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "E:\proj1\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "E:\WorkSpace\POINTMAN CARD PRINTER\Cds\New folder\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

'C:\Users\r' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The system cannot find the path specified.

make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

I have Googled and tested the solutions but none of them worked for me.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a space in your user name perhaps? C:\Users\r anything\myproject might be bad location because of the space in it.

Comment: yes i have a & in my name complete name is r&d and the path of my user is c:\users\r&d, do have any idea about this problem and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the backslash r '\r' in your path that is causing troubles.  I don't suspect the ming toolchain handles that well without escaping:

```
make.exe -f "E:\\WorkSpace\\POINTMAN CA..."
```

Or, easier, use forward slashes '/'.

```
make.exe -f "E:/WorkSpace/POINTMAN CA..."
```

You may have to escape the spaces too:

```
make.exe -f "E:/WorkSpace/POINTMAN\ CA..."
```

Comment: C:\users\r&d\ exists and contains AppDate forlder i thing the '&' causes the problem, how i can solve it ?

Comment: Another possible solution:
**cd "E:\WorkSpace\POINTMAN CARD PRINTER\Cds\New folder\"**
**make -f Makefile.win**