# dev c++ compiler error

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors

i am getting this error at compile (actually this is a very simple project and the syntax is absolutely ok)

E:\proj1\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1

this is my compiler log (dev c++ v 4.9.9.2)

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "E:\proj1\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "E:\proj1\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

'C:\Users\r' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The system cannot find the path specified.
make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

my user path is 'c:\Users\r&d', i think the '&' is makeing trouble in compile process , does anybody has any idea ?, i can not reinstall windows because i have got many softwares installed on my current windows and it is very time consuming to me, how can i fix this /

Comment: If you rename the directory to e.g. `r and d`, will it work better? What if there is no spaces like `r_and_d`?

Answer (score 0):

r&d is definitely a problem. Try surrounding it with quotes: "c:\users\r&d" and hope for the best. If it doesn't work, change the folder to something without an ampersand (you don't need to reinstall Windows for that, just create another user).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating another user without the ampersand, and then copying your profile to it to keep all your settings and application preferences, as well as documents.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try another build enviroment, like code:blocks which has its own internal build system.  You probably want make sure you are using the latest gcc mingw compiler and build system from mingw(use their installer, I think it was http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/ ), and even if you don't go with code::blocks, make sure you are using the new branch of devc++ that was forked and still being developed. One last thing is if you go with code::blocks, use a nightly build in the forum, http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/board,20.0.html as they are much more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The escape character in Windows is `^`. So try

```
C:\Users\r^&d
```